# VBA Excel more than 10 column ListBox, Populate values from other listbox

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, multiple-columns, populate

Currently I'm populating 2 listboxes side by side to provide information on a userform which is then populated to a SQL database table.

I need to turn 2 ListBox's into a single multicolumn listbox, but with 20 columns.

Here's the current code that populates the 2 listboxes:

```
Private Sub AddActualRecord()
    

    
        ListCount = frmRecordActuals.lstDirectTasks.ListCount
        
        frmRecordActuals.lstDirectTasks.AddItem
        frmRecordActuals.lstDirectTasks.list(ListCount, 0) = lstWorkItems.list(lstWorkItems.ListIndex, 0)               
        frmRecordActuals.lstDirectTasks.list(ListCount, 1) = txtPcId.value                                              
        frmRecordActuals.lstDirectTasks.list(ListCount, 2) = txtDirectActivityName.value                                
        frmRecordActuals.lstDirectTasks.list(ListCount, 3) = lstWorkItems.list(lstWorkItems.ListIndex, 1)               
        frmRecordActuals.lstDirectTasks.list(ListCount, 4) = lstWorkItems.list(lstWorkItems.ListIndex, 2)               
        frmRecordActuals.lstDirectTasks.list(ListCount, 5) = lstWorkItems.list(lstWorkItems.ListIndex, 3)               
        frmRecordActuals.lstDirectTasks.list(ListCount, 6) = lstWorkItems.list(lstWorkItems.ListIndex, 6)               
        frmRecordActuals.lstDirectTasks.list(ListCount, 7) = lstWorkItems.list(lstWorkItems.ListIndex, 4)               
        frmRecordActuals.lstDirectTasks.list(ListCount, 8) = lstWorkItems.list(lstWorkItems.ListIndex, 5)               
        frmRecordActuals.lstDirectTasks.list(ListCount, 9) = lstProcessStage.list(lstProcessStage.ListIndex, 1)         
        
        ListCount2 = frmRecordActuals.lstDirectTasks2.ListCount
        
        frmRecordActuals.lstDirectTasks2.AddItem
        frmRecordActuals.lstDirectTasks2.list(ListCount2, 0) = lstProcessStage.list(lstProcessStage.ListIndex, 0)         
        frmRecordActuals.lstDirectTasks2.list(ListCount2, 1) = cboGrade.list(cboGrade.ListIndex, 1)                      
        frmRecordActuals.lstDirectTasks2.list(ListCount2, 2) = cboGrade.list(cboGrade.ListIndex, 0)                      
        frmRecordActuals.lstDirectTasks2.list(ListCount2, 3) = cboWiderInitiative.list(cboWiderInitiative.ListIndex, 1)  
        frmRecordActuals.lstDirectTasks2.list(ListCount2, 4) = cboWiderInitiative.list(cboWiderInitiative.ListIndex, 0) 
        frmRecordActuals.lstDirectTasks2.list(ListCount2, 5) = cboHours.value                                            
        frmRecordActuals.lstDirectTasks2.list(ListCount2, 6) = cboMinutes.value                                          
        frmRecordActuals.lstDirectTasks2.list(ListCount2, 7) = lblHasCasesID.Caption                                     
        If lblHasCasesID.Caption = 1 Then
            frmRecordActuals.lstDirectTasks2.list(ListCount2, 8) = txtSelected.value
            Else: frmRecordActuals.lstDirectTasks2.list(ListCount2, 8) = "N/A"                                          
        End If
        If lblHasCasesID.Caption = 1 Then
            frmRecordActuals.lstDirectTasks2.list(ListCount2, 9) = txtDeselected.value
            Else: frmRecordActuals.lstDirectTasks2.list(ListCount2, 9) = "N/A"                                          
        End If

    
    
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated.

I've seen various solutions but cannot see how to make them fit.

EDIT: This is to replace 2 list boxes with a single listbox.

I want to remove the old 2 listboxes completely and have all data going to just 1 new 20 column listbox.

Each time this code is run it needs to add another row to the listbox. But NOT in a loop.  The code need to be able to run multiple times and add a new row each time.

Thanks

EDIT 2:

I have updated the code which now inserts all values, but this code simply overwrites the first row in the listbox eachtime the code is run.

How can I amend the code so that it populates the next row when run again?

Many Thanks.

```
Private Sub AddActualRecord()

    ListCount = frmRecordActuals.lstDirectTasks.ListCount

    Dim DirectActual(ListCount, 20) As String


    DirectActual(ListCount, 0) = lstWorkItems.list(lstWorkItems.ListIndex, 0)               
    DirectActual(ListCount, 1) = txtPcId.value                                              
    DirectActual(ListCount, 2) = txtDirectActivityName.value                                
    DirectActual(ListCount, 3) = lstWorkItems.list(lstWorkItems.ListIndex, 1)               
    DirectActual(ListCount, 4) = lstWorkItems.list(lstWorkItems.ListIndex, 2)               
    DirectActual(ListCount, 5) = lstWorkItems.list(lstWorkItems.ListIndex, 3)               
    DirectActual(ListCount, 6) = lstWorkItems.list(lstWorkItems.ListIndex, 6)              
    DirectActual(ListCount, 7) = lstWorkItems.list(lstWorkItems.ListIndex, 4)               
    DirectActual(ListCount, 8) = lstWorkItems.list(lstWorkItems.ListIndex, 5)               
    DirectActual(ListCount, 9) = lstProcessStage.list(lstProcessStage.ListIndex,1)
    DirectActual(ListCount, 10) = lstProcessStage.list(lstProcessStage.ListIndex, 0)        
    DirectActual(ListCount, 11) = cboGrade.list(cboGrade.ListIndex, 1)                      
    DirectActual(ListCount, 12) = cboGrade.list(cboGrade.ListIndex, 0)                      
    DirectActual(ListCount, 13) = cboWiderInitiative.list(cboWiderInitiative.ListIndex, 1)  
    DirectActual(ListCount, 14) = cboWiderInitiative.list(cboWiderInitiative.ListIndex, 0)  
    DirectActual(ListCount, 15) = cboHours.value                                            
    DirectActual(ListCount, 16) = cboMinutes.value                                          
    DirectActual(ListCount, 17) = lblHasCasesID.Caption                                     
    If lblHasCasesID.Caption = 1 Then
        DirectActual(ListCount, 18) = txtSelected.value
    Else: DirectActual(ListCount, 18) = "N/A"                                          
    End If
    If lblHasCasesID.Caption = 1 Then
        DirectActual(ListCount, 19) = txtDeselected.value
    Else: DirectActual(ListCount, 19) = "N/A"                                          
    End If


    With frmRecordActuals.lstDirectTasks
      .ColumnCount = 12
      .list = DirectActual
    End With
    

    
End Sub
```

Comment: Not so clear for me... Do you need populating the list directly (instead of the existing two), or from the two existing ones?

Comment: You can't use `AddItem` if you want more than 10 columns. You need to either use a range or assign an array to the `List` (or `Column`) property of the control.

Comment: Edit added to original question.  
I'm not experienced with arrays, and help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Still not clear... Do you like to firstly fill the two existing list boxes, then to take their items and fill another list box (with 20 columns)? Then, for each code run to add another row in all three list boxes?

Comment: Hi FaneDuru-  No I just want to replace the 2 listboxes with a single ListBox (20 columns), pulling the data direct into that new listbox.  I don't want any data going to the old listboxes.

Then when code runs again add direct to the new single listbox.

I'm trying to remove/delete the old structure of 2 listboxes, and replace with a single listbox.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I asked you about this aspect, you did not say anything, edited your question and talk about two in one... The important idea is the fact that you cannot use `AddItem` for more than 10 columns. So, you must firstly load the data in an array, let us say, `arrData` and then simple use `listBoxName.List = arrData`.

Comment: Further Update (Edit 2) to original post showing the updated code I have created, but this only ever populates Row 0 of the listbox and overwrites the row each time its run.  How can I update the code so that it populates the next row each time the code is run.

Many Thanks

Comment: If you repeat the same code, of course, it loads the new array. You should create a new array, where to extract the existing loaded values and after that fill the array to be loaded with existing elements plus the new data. The array list can be simple extracted as `arrList = listBox.List`. The list box can be loaded with a zero based array or with the 1 based one. But take care when `ReDim` the final one.

Comment: if not something confidential and you can share the workbook in discussion, I can try helping you with a piece of working code. Of course, if all the necessary data to be loaded exist in the same workbook and not extracted from a exterior source...

Comment: FaneDuru, Hi, unfortunately I cannot share as the data is confidential, and the data being used to populate the user selected values in the  comboboxes and  listboxes originates from a MS SQL database so you would not be able to replicate unfortunately.

Thanks anyway for your help.

Comment: OK. I will try making a blind answer, based only on what I could deduce from your question/code/clarifications...

Comment: Please, test the code I posted. In some minutes I will leave my office and I will be driving. I can see your comments on the road, when stopped to the traffic lights, but do something in terms of (eventual) error correction in some hours, when I will be at home...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, test the next code. Not tested, of course, but it should work:

```
Private Sub AddActualRecord()
    Dim ListCount As Long
    ListCount = frmRecordActuals.lstDirectTasks.ListCount
    
    If ListCount = 0 Then
        Dim DirectActual(ListCount, 20) As String
    
        DirectActual(ListCount, 0) = lstWorkItems.list(lstWorkItems.ListIndex, 0)
        DirectActual(ListCount, 1) = txtPcId.value
        DirectActual(ListCount, 2) = txtDirectActivityName.value
        DirectActual(ListCount, 3) = lstWorkItems.list(lstWorkItems.ListIndex, 1)
        DirectActual(ListCount, 4) = lstWorkItems.list(lstWorkItems.ListIndex, 2)
        DirectActual(ListCount, 5) = lstWorkItems.list(lstWorkItems.ListIndex, 3)
        DirectActual(ListCount, 6) = lstWorkItems.list(lstWorkItems.ListIndex, 6)
        DirectActual(ListCount, 7) = lstWorkItems.list(lstWorkItems.ListIndex, 4)
        DirectActual(ListCount, 8) = lstWorkItems.list(lstWorkItems.ListIndex, 5)
        DirectActual(ListCount, 9) = lstProcessStage.list(lstProcessStage.ListIndex, 1)
        DirectActual(ListCount, 10) = lstProcessStage.list(lstProcessStage.ListIndex, 0)
        DirectActual(ListCount, 11) = cboGrade.list(cboGrade.ListIndex, 1)
        DirectActual(ListCount, 12) = cboGrade.list(cboGrade.ListIndex, 0)
        DirectActual(ListCount, 13) = cboWiderInitiative.list(cboWiderInitiative.ListIndex, 1)
        DirectActual(ListCount, 14) = cboWiderInitiative.list(cboWiderInitiative.ListIndex, 0)
        DirectActual(ListCount, 15) = cboHours.value
        DirectActual(ListCount, 16) = cboMinutes.value
        DirectActual(ListCount, 17) = lblHasCasesID.Caption
        If lblHasCasesID.Caption = 1 Then
            DirectActual(ListCount, 18) = txtSelected.value
        Else
            DirectActual(ListCount, 18) = "N/A"
        End If
        If lblHasCasesID.Caption = 1 Then
            DirectActual(ListCount, 19) = txtDeselected.value
        Else
            DirectActual(ListCount, 19) = "N/A"
        End If
        With frmRecordActuals.lstDirectTasks
          .ColumnCount = 12
          .list = DirectActual
        End With
    Else
        Dim arrList, arrFin, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
        
        arrList = frmRecordActuals.lstDirectTasks.list 'extract the list box elements in an array
        ReDim arrFin(0 To UBound(arrList) + 1, 0 To UBound(arrList, 2)) 'redim the final array
        For i = 0 To UBound(arrList)                   'load the existing elements in the final array
            For j = 0 To UBound(arrList, 2)
                arrFin(k, j) = arrList(i, j)
            Next j
            k = k + 1
        Next i
        'add the new elements in the final array:
        arrFin(k, 0) = lstWorkItems.list(lstWorkItems.ListIndex, 0)
        arrFin(k, 1) = txtPcId.value
        arrFin(k, 2) = txtDirectActivityName.value
        arrFin(k, 3) = lstWorkItems.list(lstWorkItems.ListIndex, 1)
        arrFin(k, 4) = lstWorkItems.list(lstWorkItems.ListIndex, 2)
        arrFin(k, 5) = lstWorkItems.list(lstWorkItems.ListIndex, 3)
        arrFin(k, 6) = lstWorkItems.list(lstWorkItems.ListIndex, 6)
        arrFin(k, 7) = lstWorkItems.list(lstWorkItems.ListIndex, 4)
        arrFin(k, 8) = lstWorkItems.list(lstWorkItems.ListIndex, 5)
        arrFin(k, 9) = lstProcessStage.list(lstProcessStage.ListIndex, 1)
        arrFin(k, 10) = lstProcessStage.list(lstProcessStage.ListIndex, 0)
        arrFin(k, 11) = cboGrade.list(cboGrade.ListIndex, 1)
        arrFin(k, 12) = cboGrade.list(cboGrade.ListIndex, 0)
        arrFin(k, 13) = cboWiderInitiative.list(cboWiderInitiative.ListIndex, 1)
        arrFin(k, 14) = cboWiderInitiative.list(cboWiderInitiative.ListIndex, 0)
        arrFin(k, 15) = cboHours.value
        arrFin(k, 16) = cboMinutes.value
        arrFin(k, 17) = lblHasCasesID.Caption
        If lblHasCasesID.Caption = 1 Then
            arrFin(k, 18) = txtSelected.value
        Else
            arrFin(k, 18) = "N/A"
        End If
        If lblHasCasesID.Caption = 1 Then
            arrFin(k, 19) = txtDeselected.value
        Else
            arrFin(k, 19) = "N/A"
        End If
        'load the listbox with the cumulated array:
        frmRecordActuals.lstDirectTasks.list = arrFin
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: That is excellent.  Exactly what i was looking for.
Thank you very much for your persistence and help.
Apologies for not explaining the issue properly.

Comment: @dori2o: Glad I (finaly) could help! I am leaving right  now...